# Failed To Resolve error when Debugging in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, c#-4.0, linker, xamarin.ios

In The project options Linker behaviour is set to Don't Link My App is working fine but the Linker behaviour is set to Link FrameWork SDK only below Error can be occured.

Here Is My Error:`Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter" reference from "System.Xml.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" (MT2002)`

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The linker doesn´t know it should include `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter` in your app, even if your project has a reference to it. This usually happens when using reflection.

So you can add a dummy class to your project, with a method that actually uses that class. Take a look how this is done [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/AutoViewExamples/AutoViewExamples.Touch/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs).

It would be something like:

```
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(XmlReflectionImporter importer)
    {
        importer.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

"DoSomething()" is not real. You should replace it with the method you are actually using. And you should do the same with other methods and properties used in your project

Comment: Thanks for your responce xleon.where can i add this class in my project.

Comment: It doesn´t actually matter, but you can add it in the root project folder

Comment: importer.dosomething method does not work so which method can be wirked please tell me.

Comment: which method can i use for solve this error,i can not understand please help me

Comment: Update your answer with the portion of code that is generating the exception and maybe I could help you better